# Looking for better approach for conditional inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
void C :: setmethodForC(...)
{
   B::setmethod(...);
}

class C: public A, public B
{

   public:

    void setmethodForC();
    .....

}
```

In above code A and B are two services which class C using. Now this code is valid for multiple targets and all targets do not support service B. So i needed conditional inheritance where service B only enabled for specific targets. For this i made below changes to disable use of service B in C.

```
#ifdef B_SUPPORTED
void C :: setmethodForC(...)
{
   B::setmethod(...);
}
#endif

class C: public A
#ifdef B_SUPPORTED
, public B
#endif
{

   public:
#ifdef B_SUPPORTED
    void setmethodForC();
    .....
#endif

}
```

As this is compiled fine but is there any better way to do this?

Comment: You should be more specific with your use case. Normally I would go with a "prefer composition rather than inheritance", but I can't say if this fit for you, the informations are too vague

Comment: @Moia edited question for more details.

Comment: Do you have any reason to add new method instead of leave those empty if functionality is missing?

Comment: This is classic example of [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please explain WHY you need this, since I'm sure there is better and simpler way to solve your actual problem. It is possible to do what you have requested, but it is strange in this context and it qualifies as advanced solution (I do not wish to mess your mind).

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear in your question why inheritance is neeed here, you can achieve the result that you want using composition and the null object pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern, here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct OptionalService
{
    virtual void someMethod() = 0;
    virtual ~OptionalService() {}
};

struct DoSomethingService final : OptionalService
{
    void someMethod() override { std::cout << "Do Something" << std::endl; }
};

struct NoActionService final : OptionalService
{
    void someMethod() override {  }
};

class MyClass
{
    std::unique_ptr<OptionalService> _service;
public:
    explicit MyClass(std::unique_ptr<OptionalService> service) : _service(std::move(service)) {}
    void someMethod( ) { _service->someMethod(); }
};

int main() {
    MyClass noAction(std::make_unique<NoActionService>());

    noAction.someMethod();

    MyClass someAction(std::make_unique<DoSomethingService>());

    someAction.someMethod();

    return 0;
}
```

Something similar can be obtain using static polymorphism ase well, it will spare you the interface class:

```
template<typename Service>
class MyClassB
{
    Service _service;
public:
    explicit MyClassB(const Service& s = Service()) : _service(s) {}
    void someMethod() { _service.someMethod(); }
};

typedef MyClassB<NoActionService> MyClassBNoAction;
typedef MyClassB<DoSomethingService> MyClassBSomething;
int main() {
    MyClassBNoAction noAction;

    noAction.someMethod();

    MyClassBSomething someAction;

    someAction.someMethod();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is impossible to tell if OP actually needs that. Anyway you do not have to use `std::unique_ptr` here. Passing service by reference will prevent null and do not force use of heap.

Comment: I agree, the question is vague, but I think this technique "could" be useful and it was way too much to be put in the comment. I get your point of using a reference instead of unique_ptr. But in that case we will use "aggregation" instead of "composition" and it will introduce considerations on lifetime of the service and assignability of the class.

Answer (score 0):

As already said the question is not much clear and this is probably an XY problem. Said that, one way to deal with different target specific class is to move the problem from the definition to the creation.

The target specific class are now children of the generic one

**foo.h**

```
class FooBase {};

class FooGeneric : public FooBase {};

class FooTargetSpecificA : public FooGeneric{};

class FooTargetSpecificB : public FooGeneric{};
```

Move the target option to compile time variable. There are other ways to achieve that though.

**target.h**

```
#ifdef A_SUPPORTED
constexpr bool HasFeatureA = true;
#else
constexpr bool HasFeatureA = false;
#endif

#ifdef B_SUPPORTED
constexpr bool HasFeatureB = true;
#else
constexpr bool HasFeatureB = false;
#endif
```

Delegate the construction of your object to a factory with a compile time check for the right class.

**factory.h**

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "target.h"

inline std::unique_ptr<FooBase> createFoo()
{
   if constexpr (HasFeatureA)
      return std::make_unique<FooTargetSpecificA>();
   else if constexpr (HasFeatureB)
      return std::make_unique<FooTargetSpecificB>();
   else
      return std::make_unique<FooGenerc>();
}
```